# Is it possible that iOS Safari keeps a page opened while reloading that very same page?

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, caching, socket.io

I have a Node.Js app that uses Socket.IO for a chat-like feature.

It works fine on desktop, but what happens sometimes on an iPhone is that when a user loads the page, they'll load it again and the system thinks that there's two people viewing this page already.

I've experienced this kind of caching error before with other stuff in my app (like it would take a few reloads for the page to fetch the new data – something that never happens to desktop and something that has to do with caching also I think).

Did anybody encounter a similar problem and know a solution?

Maybe there's some kind of directive I can give in the `meta` tags of my app to tell IOS browsers treat it differently?

Thanks!

Comment: The socket.io socket on the old page (the one no longer visible) should disconnect itself in a short amount of time.  If you log disconnects in your server, do you see this?

Comment: yes it does, but on the phone it takes too long. i also noticed that sometimes it takes a minute for the page updates to be shown whereas on desktop it's instant.

Comment: How long does it take for the server disconnect to come through?  And, please define "too long"?  What would be acceptable?

Comment: about a minute or so - the same time it takes for page cache to be reloaded - so i think these issues are connected.

Comment: Why is one minute of overlap a problem?

Comment: It very well could be that Safari prioritizes getting the new page on screen and then, after that is done, it worries about cleaning up the old one.  If I were structuring code like that, I could see making a design choice like that since usually what the user wants is to see the new content as soon as possible.

Comment: Makes sense. It's a problem because I can't have any overlaps for Socket.io not to open a new additional session each time a user reloads the page (as the browser keeps the old page somewhere in memory)

Comment: A socket.io connection will NOT survive a page reload.  A page reload is a total replacement of all page resources including webSockets.  It seems you could make your server design allow more than one connection from the same client and not worry about this issue.  What happens if the same user has it open on both phone and laptop or in two tabs on their phone or two tabs on their laptop?  Does your server complain then too?

Comment: Well in my case it DOES survive. I can't afford to have two connections survive simultaneously on the phone but I want to keep that feature for the desktop version. As I want to have one code for all devices I want to find a good solution that will simply address the issue of ios browser caching.

Comment: But, you said the dual phone socket during a reload goes away after one minute.  So, I still don't understand the problem?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot afford even a few seconds...

Comment: And, I've been asking you why you cannot afford even a few seconds.  If you ask me that's a brittle server design.  You should fix that so it's no big deal if there's an overlap.  You're unlikely to change the IOS behavior.  And, I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if there were other browsers that have overlap too.

Comment: Put another way, your server has made a design assumption that proves to not be true.  Apparently, it has assumed that a user will never have more than one socket open.  You've now shown that that assumption is not a valid assumption.  It is not the way Safari works.  I think you'll have more luck changing your server code to live with that than changing Safari's behavior.